# Phpmyadmin will not allow empty password

Tags: ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and I installed phpmyadmin(version 4:3.3.10-1). But when I try to use phpmyadmin, I get the error message as

```
Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)
```

I edited the config.inc.php located in /etc/phpmyadmin to uncomment the line `AllowNoPassword = TRUE` and restarted both apache2 server and mysql server, but I get the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the server;

```
use mysql; 
update user set password=PASSWORD("") where User='root'; 
flush privileges;
```

Also, make sure that /etc/phpmyadmin is relevant. Perhaps the config file is read from the folder where PHPMyAdmin is installed.